# How to add DATE to doctrine query?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a date field in `Y-m-d H:i:s` format. Now user can search by using date only. I have query like this:

```
$qb->andWhere('DATE(vc.updatedDatetime) >= :startDate AND DATE(vc.updatedDatetime) <= :endDate')
->setParameter('startDate', $filterArray['startDate'])
->setParameter('endDate', $filterArray['endDate']);
```

I have added following lines at my `doctrine.yaml` file.

```
    dql:
        string_functions:
            DATE: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Date
```

But I am getting following error:

```
Attempted to load class "Date" from namespace "DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql".
Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g. "Twig_Extensions_Extension_Date" or "Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Date"?
```

Comment: I found the issue. `composer require beberlei/DoctrineExtensions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you *could* create your own extension to add the `DATE` function to Doctrine, or download something like [beberlei/DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) to do it for you, in the end is a waste of time. You do not need it.

You could simply do:

```
$qb
    ->andWhere('vc.updatedDatetime > :startDate')
    ->andWhere('vc.updatedDatetime < :endDate')
    ->setParameter('startDate', $startDate)
    ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate)
```

For your start date, you need nothing but to use the `>` operator. A date time string without a time part will be treated as a datetime with the time part set to `00:00:00`.

For the end date, you simply need to use the `<` operator, and **add one day** to whatever date the user provides.

E.g.

```
$endDate = (new DateTime($filterArray['endDate']))->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))
```

Assuming the provided date is in "YYYY-MM-DD" format, which seems to be the case because of how you are using your code, the above would suffice.